# Sticky Header - Scroll - CSS / jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, header, sticky

I wish to create a sticky header. Everytime that the user scrolls down AND the original header goes away, then the "sticky" header should kick in.

I currently use this:

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#sticky').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            //$('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', float: 'right'});
            $('#sticky').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('#sticky').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Although, the current one add the class "sticky" whenever a user just does a scroll, and not when the original header should be gone.

Regards

Comment: This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/ZQwhL/embedded/result

Comment: But my original header is located at the top to begin with.

Comment: If it's at the top then why does the user have to scroll for it to be sticky? Just set it to `position:fixed;` to begin with: http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/ZQwhL/1/embedded/result,html,css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap him with a `div` with `id="whateveryouwannacallit"`

and set:

```
#whateveryouwannacalltit{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you won't need wrapping. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stuck = $('#header');
  var start = $(div).offset().top;
  $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(stuck).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
    $(stuck).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
  });
});
```

---

Credit goes to this page: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/scroll-fix-header-jquery-facebook/