# How to add sticky header

Tags: html, css

I want to make a webpage with sticky header like the header in stackoverflow itself. When we scroll the page then also the header remains in its position . How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky Header - Scroll - CSS / jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214380/sticky-header-scroll-css-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

That can be done with the css property `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

If you are using bootstrap then you can use .navbar-fixed-top class to fix is always on top.

Answer (score 1):

this is might be what you are looking for!!!

**Note:** `Jquery` and `javascript` is only used for scroll effect, while "just sticking" effect can be achieved by using `HTML` and `CSS` only.

```js
var  mn = $(".main-nav");
mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
        mn.addClass(mns);
    } else {
        mn.removeClass(mns);
    }
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
header {
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #f07057;
}
.main-nav,
.main {
  position: relative; 
}
.main-nav {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 150;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
header,
.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.main {
  background: #f2f2e8;
  padding: 110px 50px 50px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>This is a Sticky Nav</h1> 
</header>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <a href="#">Nav Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 4</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut, aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

  <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>

  <p>Tum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis pharetra odio, sit amet consectetur elit facilisis ac. Praesent eget tristique ipsum. Donec malesuada bibendum lacinia. Praesent non purus sodales, pulvinar mi vitae, tincidunt leo. Phasellus vitae elit ut nisl semper fringilla id rutrum dolor. Donec a massa adipiscing, cursus risus vitae, porttitor tortor. Nullam sagittis est sapien, sit amet pharetra turpis imperdiet vel. Etiam sit amet ligula pretium, vulputate eros ac, bibendum velit. Aenean convallis ante purus, ac bibendum orci laoreet ac. Donec a convallis mauris. Nulla non lacus non ipsum pretium tempor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean at ipsum vulputate, sagittis dui ut, pharetra neque. Nam eget sodales orci. Aliquam pharetra nunc at nisl pellentesque, nec fringilla enim iaculis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut, aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

  <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>

  <p>Tum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis pharetra odio, sit amet consectetur elit facilisis ac. Praesent eget tristique ipsum. Donec malesuada bibendum lacinia. Praesent non purus sodales, pulvinar mi vitae, tincidunt leo. Phasellus vitae elit ut nisl semper fringilla id rutrum dolor. Donec a massa adipiscing, cursus risus vitae, porttitor tortor. Nullam sagittis est sapien, sit amet pharetra turpis imperdiet vel. Etiam sit amet ligula pretium, vulputate eros ac, bibendum velit. Aenean convallis ante purus, ac bibendum orci laoreet ac. Donec a convallis mauris. Nulla non lacus non ipsum pretium tempor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean at ipsum vulputate, sagittis dui ut, pharetra neque. Nam eget sodales orci. Aliquam pharetra nunc at nisl pellentesque, nec fringilla enim iaculis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With just HTML & CSS

```css
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```